# Custom animation of two properties in CALayer by a new custom property

Tags: ios, swift, animation, calayer

I can animate a `CALayer` object by changing a property using `CABasicAnimation` as with this code:

```
let animationOfPropertyOpacity = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animationOfPropertyOpacity.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
animationOfPropertyOpacity.fromValue = 0
animationOfPropertyOpacity.toValue = 1
myLayer.addAnimation(animationOfPropertyOpacity, forKey: "fade")
```

In this case the animation will create a linear interpolation between 0 to 1. I can do the same with other properties like scale, position or rotation.

What If I want to move from point A (0,3) to point B (3,0) but making a circle respect to point C (0,0)?

I want to keep using `fromValue` to `toValue`, but animating a custom property that I've made called rotation. Rotation will calculate each interpolation value based on point C as center and making a radius from that center.

Where do I need to put the function that calculates each step?

I've tried subclassing `CALayer` and adding a custom property called rotation. Then adding code to `needsDisplayForKey` to redraw the layer:

```
@NSManaged var rotation: CGFloat

override class func needsDisplayForKey(key: String) -> Bool {
       if (key == "rotation") {
            return true
        }

        return super.needsDisplayForKey(key)
    }
```

This calls `drawInContext` and makes the whole `CALayer` black. I have a print in `drawInContext` and it doesn't get called when changing other properties like opacity, it seems it's not necessary to redraw the layer.

There should be a method that is being called each frame of the animation in `CALayer` where I could implement a function before applying the changes.

I'm also unable to find the right place to implement the functionality of the custom property that I've created to actually reflect the change even without animation. Let's say a property `customOpacity` that just inverts the effects of opacity and updating the layer accordingly. I only could make that through a function `updateRotation(rotation: CGFloat)`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to rotate your layer?

Comment: No, I want to move it from point A to point B but not in a linear interpolation, I want the layer to move making a circle around point C. edit: I also may want to do something else with the movement value on each frame of the animation, so a path animation won't work.

Comment: it's possible this question is the same  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164762/cabasicanimation-of-custom-property-in-swift4

Comment: I think this is the hardest thing to do in all of iOS !

Comment: You can animate a layer's position along a path by setting [the `path` property of a `CAKeyframeAnimation`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation/1412474-path?language=swift) Have you tried that?